# Getting error : incorrect syntax near group by for document db query through code

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Here is the example query :

```
List<Document> documentList =
    documentClient
        .queryDocuments(
            collectionLink,
            "SELECT sum(c.copyCount) as count, c.pk, c.jobId,c.to,c[\"from\"]\n" +
                    "FROM root c where c.jobId=\"58a08e66768d4330940a9546c19a94ab\"\n" +
                    "group by c.pk, c.jobId,c.to,c[\"from\"]",
            option)
        .getQueryIterable()
        .toList();
```

While hitting this query through code, I am getting error as :

```
 {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":153,"end":158},"code":"SC1001","messa
ge":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'group'."}]}
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Please remove the new line characters (\n) from your query.

Comment: @GauravMantri I edited the query , but still the same issue :   List<Document> documentList =
        documentClient
            .queryDocuments(
                collectionLink,
                "SELECT sum(c.copyCount) as copyCount, c.pk, c.jobId,c.destination, c.status, c.to,c[\"from\"] FROM root c where c.jobId=\"58a08e66768d4330940a9546c19a94ab\" group by c.pk, c.jobId,c.destination,c.status,c.to,c[\"from\"]",option)
            .getQueryIterable()
            .toList();

Comment: I am using this version of document db :   implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-documentdb-rx', version: '0.9.0-rc2'

Comment: Please edit to also show your query as a standalone, properly-formatted query, instead of escaped within line of code - it's not easy to see the actual query in its entirety. Aside from that, please show a bit of sample data. Also, have you tried running the standalone query from the portal, and do you get the same error?

Comment: One more thing: Please don't post code in comments - there's no formatting, and it's very difficult to read.